# redirecting only if the domain url is not followed by anything

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I would like to redirect a user to a special directory with a landing page
but only in case the users type the domain name or the domain name followed by a slash and NOTHING else.

how would I state such condition in htaccess?

the reason for this is that I have a web application on the same domain and the urls have to be available for it to function properly. I want users to be redirected on the landing page only in case they come to the domain name.

Comment: I would look at the Wordpress .htaccess, and just replace the index.php portion of it with a redirect. What that htaccess file is going to do is if a user lands on anything that isn't a real location it will send them to the index.php currently as is for processing otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use code like this in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /special-dir [R=301,L]
```

This will do external redirection in the sense that the URL in browser will also change to `http://www.mydomain.com/special-dir`

Comment: fantastic, thank you! what about adding option without www just for completeness?

Comment: You're welcome. I edited my answer to make www optional in domain name.